# Cypher / Retrieving latest notification per Topic

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Let's suppose this model:

```
(notification)-[:CONCERNS]->(user)
```

To make things simpler, let's imagine that each `notification` is related to a Chat entry associated to a specific topic.
So when user enters into the `Football` topic and he types : "Hi guys !", a `notification` is eventually created containing those properties (among others):

- `topidId` (String)
- `occurredOn` (timestamp (long))
- `body` (String - excerpt of the Chat message)

Note that there aren't direct relationships between `notification` and `topic`.
Indeed, in the future, I don't want to pollute Neo4j with the user's notification mechanism.
Redis or RDBMS would be far better to handle that.

Basically, if I run this query:

```
MATCH (user:User {_id: "30c62b1f-4556-4966-b60c-3547d4c8d522"})
WITH user 
MATCH user<-[:CONCERNS]-(n:Notification)
RETURN n.topicId AS TopicId, n.body as Body
ORDER BY n.occurredOn DESC
```

It could return:

```
TopicID     Body
123         Fine and you !  // I want to retain only this for Football (123 being Football)
123         Hey! How are you?   
456         Yes, I'm here !  // I want to retain only this for tennis (456 being Tennis)
456         Are you here?
```

How to alter the query to get this result, being the **latest** message per topic.

```
  123     Fine and you !
  456     Yes, I'm here !
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
MATCH (user:User {_id: "30c62b1f-4556-4966-b60c-3547d4c8d522"})
MATCH user<-[:CONCERNS]-(n:Notification)
WITH user, collect(n) AS notifications
ORDER BY n.occurredOn DESC
WITH user, notifications[0] AS notification
RETURN notification.topicId AS TopicId, notification.body as Body
ORDER BY notification.occurredOn DESC
```

Comment: I can't test it right now ( internet connection issue on my desktop) , but I think that you forget that a user can talk within MANY topics. Thus, if you only sort by occurredon Desc, you would blend them all... returning a single result for all of them. I expect the latest message PER topic sent by a specific user.  thanks ;)